# Editar Txt en bat de miles de directorios

Tags: batch

Como puedo editar txt en diferentes direciorios INFINITOS.

Hola tengo una duda quiero editar un txt en diferentes directorios me explico tengo una APP mis clientes descargan e instalan en MIles de direcciones diferentes X Y Z. etc.

En el tengo un Txt que quiero borrar y modificar con un Bat tengo parte del Codigo. pero no se como editar donde exista el archivo. mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
@echo off
del /q (CD se supone busca donde exista caso de busqueda es /s)inicios.ini
echo.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set new_line=UPDATE_END
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (**(como busco aqui el directorio o DONDE?)** inicios.ini) do (set "resultado=%%A")&call :sub
copy salida.txt inicios.ini
del salida.txt
goto:eof
:sub
echo !resultado:UPDATE_START=%new_line%!>>salida.txt
```